# How can i use a variable value to call an object property?

Tags: javascript

```
    for(i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
                
                let ingredient = meal.strIngredient + i
}
```

How can I put the value of variable i, in front of meal.strIngredient to pass in all strIngredient??

I need : meal.strIngredient1, meal.strIngredient2, meal.strIngredient3, meal.strIngredient4 ...

Comment: So many duplicates, so many tutorials. (ps. in this case an _array_ might be better suited, including relevant updates to the model.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
 meal['strIngredient' + i]
```